# Formidable can not upload files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, formidable

I am writing a simple file upload server in nodejs and using `Formidable` to handle file uploads. However the `file` event is never triggered. The `progress` event always prints 0 and 100. What's wrong here?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><span class=
            "btn btn-primary btn-file">Browse&hellip; <input type=
            "file"></span></span> <input class="form-control" id="filebox"
            name="file" readonly type="text">
        </div>
    </div><input class="btn btn-primary btn-file" type="submit" value=
    "Upload">
</form>
```

**Node.js:**

```
case "POST":
    if(req.url == "/upload"){
        if(!isFormData(req)){
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.end("Bad Request");
            return;
        }
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.on("file",function(name,file){
            console.log("uploaded: " + name);
        });
        form.on("end",function(){
            res.end("Upload complete");
        });
        form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected){
            var percent = Math.floor(bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100);
            console.log(percent);
        });
        form.parse(req);
    }
break;
```

Comment: Going over their support, I found this: *Currently, file upload fields must be on the last page of a multi-page form or the file will not be uploaded.*. Is this related to my post?

Comment: Never heard of multi-page forms before.  I don't think it applies to you and your single page form, unless they're saying file uploads MUST be on the last page of a multi page form.

Comment: @djb if I send back html from my server that just contains the form tag (with file input, no divs, etc), it works :-/

Comment: Huh. And if you wrap the whole thing in another div? You could also maybe do away with divs, and use spans for the formatting instead? I think they're interchangeable for the most part